# Reason for minimize PCB tracd width?

Tags: pcb-design

As I know we need larger trace width to handle higher current but some PCB got small PCB trace for signal. Why they don't use large trace if it's no any disadvantage?. Are there any reason or factor for minimizing trace width? (ignore space constrain)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Impedance control (discontinuities), and parasitic capacitance (two sides of the same coin really) if you are running over a ground plane.

In addition, the larger a trace is, the higher the chance you might have to narrow it down to squeeze it past something and that introduces an impedance discontinuity. Sometimes it's difficult to tell in advance if you might run out of room and if your trace is too big you have to reduce it down which might mean you have to re-arrange a bunch of stuff.

Also, it can make it more difficult to solder. More heatsinking. I guess this could also cause tombstoning in some cases if you have a small component with landings sitting right on the a giant trace.

Also, have you ever routed a board? It can be mind numbingly tedious to keep on changing trace widths. I used to try and make my traces match the width of the pads, but after running into so many traces that run to multiple components each  with different pad sizes I threw my hands up in the air and just used the same 0.3mm trace width for every signal when it was not critical.

Comment: Yes I also use 16 or 24 mil for all non-critical trace with no doubt until I found some circuit with high frequenct use very small trace over plenty of space.

Comment: high frequency is the point here. If your signal is not possible to be understood and modeled as a simple current on a conductor, but needs to be understood as a wave traveling between the conductor and e.g. the ground plane, then you don't get to choose the width of the trace – it needs to be of a specific characteristic impedance. See: *Transmission Line Theory*.

Answer (score 1):

If you need impedance control, it's essential to set the trace width to achieve the right unit capacitance and inductance. The exact width will vary, depending on the target impedance and other factors. A needlessly-wide trace would work against that.

If you don't need impedance control, it nevertheless is still desirable to reduce trace capacitance to improve signal transition time and reduce drive power (narrower traces have less area, and therefore less capacitance.)

Ultimately, it's more work to make arbitrarily-sized traces for signals. You would settle on a set of layout rules and use them throughout your design.

Power planes are a different matter. It's often the case that these use wide shapes, to improve both power integrity and thermal dissipation.

Answer (score 0):

Although you say "(ignore space constrain)", I think the main factor governing track width is space constraints.

With through-hole parts, we often want to run tracks between IC pins - the pin spacing and pad diameter place a limit on the maximum width of track there, and it is convenient to use that same width everywhere, rather than reducing the width only when needed.  With surface-mount parts there are similar spacing concerns to get tracks between component pads.

With PCB CAD programs, it is generally most convenient to use the same track width everwhere - it is extra work to change track width, so wider tracks are only used where needed, for extra power-handling capability.

Comment: anything to do with high frequency?